# What am I doing wrong with this MERGE / INSERT query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have a database table that I want to update with SQL. Basically, it carries a set of description information for parts of a timetable booklet, but that isn't important. Some of the data is entered already via an application, but it is time consuming and blocks of it are "boiler plate" that want to be updated each week. In some cases, I may have missed entering the data via the application, and so also want to create data automatically if it doesn't exist.

That leads me to use a MERGE query, as follows:

```
MERGE INTO TTP_LINE_DESCRIPTION o
USING
  (SELECT DISTINCT lv.lv_nv_id TLDE_NV_ID,
                   lv.lv_id TLDE_LV_ID,
                   dir.dir_id TLDE_DIR_ID,
                   8 TLDE_MED_FLAG,
                   1 TLDE_TYPE,
                   0 TLDE_SORT_NO,
                   'Timetable valid from ' || to_char(lv.lv_valid_from,'DD/MM/YYYY') || ' until ' || nvl2(lv.lv_valid_until,to_char(lv.lv_valid_until,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'further notice') TLDE_TEXT,
                   0 TLDE_ALIGNMENT, 
                   null TLDE_FONT_SIZE, 
                   null TLDE_FONT_STYLE 
   FROM LINE_VERSION lv 
   JOIN line_point_sequence lps ON (lv.lv_id = lps.lps_lv_id)
   JOIN direction dir ON (dir.dir_id = lps.lps_dir_id)
   where lv.lv_nv_id=3799 and lv.lv_id=10455244) n

ON (o.TLDE_NV_ID=n.TLDE_NV_ID 
   and o.TLDE_LV_ID=n.TLDE_LV_ID 
   and o.TLDE_DIR_ID=n.TLDE_DIR_ID 
   and o.TLDE_TYPE=n.TLDE_TYPE 
   and o.TLDE_SORT_NO=n.TLDE_SORT_NO)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET o.TLDE_TEXT=n.TLDE_TEXT,
      o.TLDE_ALIGNMENT=n.TLDE_ALIGNMENT,
      o.TLDE_FONT_SIZE=n.TLDE_FONT_SIZE,
      o.TLDE_FONT_STYLE=n.TLDE_FONT_STYLE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (o.tlde_id, o.tlde_nv_id, o.tlde_lv_id, o.tlde_dir_id, 
           o.tlde_med_flag, o.tlde_type, o.tlde_sort_no, o.tlde_text,
           o.tlde_alignment, o.tlde_font_size, o.tlde_font_style, 
           o.updated_by, o.updated_on, o.updated_prog)
   VALUES ((select max(tld.tlde_id)+1 from TTP_LINE_DESCRIPTION tld),
           n.tlde_nv_id, n.tlde_lv_id, n.tlde_dir_id, n.tlde_med_flag,
           n.tlde_type, n.tlde_sort_no, n.tlde_text, n.tlde_alignment, 
           n.tlde_font_size, n.tlde_font_style, 'STUARTR', 
           SYSDATE, 'PL/SQL Developer');
```

There is one thing to note here, which is the WHERE clause in the SELECT DISTINCT. The `lv.lv_id=10455244` is a reference that I know will force the select to return only a single pair of rows in that SELECT, so that I can limit my testing. For this purpose, 10455244 is a valid value that is NOT currently in the TTP_LINE_DESCRIPTION table.

When I use a value that is in the table, the WHEN MATCHED code executes correctly, and updates a pair of rows in 0.016s.

Running the SELECT statement on its own using the value I have shown above returns the two rows that need adding in 0.109s.

Getting the max id and adding one to it (this is the primary key) as per the first item in the VALUES line at the end takes 0s.

Finally, if I write an INSERT INTO and explicitly write all of the values that I want to write for one of the rows, I can do the INSERT of one row in 0.016s.

But put it all together and ... nothing. The execution just sits there, executing, and doesn't appear to end. Or I get nervous waiting to see if it will end. I've left it a reasonable time, and nothing seems to go in.

So what's going on, and why won't it do what I think that it should?

Comment: did you: check plan, did you plan/time: select * TTP_LINE_DESCRIPTION o inner join
  (SELECT DISTINCT ... ) n
ON (o.TLDE_NV_ID=n.TLDE_NV_ID 
   and o.TLDE_LV_ID=n.TLDE_LV_ID 
   and o.TLDE_DIR_ID=n.TLDE_DIR_ID 
   and o.TLDE_TYPE=n.TLDE_TYPE 
   and o.TLDE_SORT_NO=n.TLDE_SORT_NO)

Comment: No, but having now done so it takes 0.016s to return 0 rows (because I am checking for a NOT MATCHED condition) or if I remove the lv_id that I know isn't there, I return 1049 rows in 0.905s, neither of which are particularly slow.

Comment: Also, why has the question been downvoted? I'm still new to a lot of SQL, so I may be doing something stupid, the question can be answered, and I have shown by breaking it down and testing different sections that I have been trying different ways to get my code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
create table t (id, nv_id, val) as (select 1, 101, 'A' from dual);

merge into t o
using (
  select 102 nv_id, 'P' val from dual union all
  select 103 nv_id, 'Q' val from dual ) n
on (o.nv_id = n.nv_id)
when matched then update set val = n.val
when not matched then 
  insert (o.id, o.nv_id, o.val)
  values ((select max(id) + 1 from t), n.nv_id, n.val);
```

In my case it worked, but `id` for inserted rows was the same: `2`. When I did rollback and added primary key constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key(id);
```

`merge` caused error - unique constraint violated. I suspect that this is something connected to your `tlde_id`, maybe not constraint but something else. Generating values this way is a big no-no. If your Oracle version is 12c or higher you can change this column to auto generated

```
generated by default on null as identity
```

or in older versions use sequence and trigger (find max `id`, add 1 and set it as starting value for sequence)

```
create sequence seq_t_id start with 2;

create or replace trigger t_on_insert  
  before insert on t for each row
begin
  select seq_t_id.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
```

Then modify your `merge`, either by removing `id` from insert clause or just insert `null` and trigger will set proper values:

```
merge into t o
using (
  select 102 nv_id, 'P' val from dual union all
  select 103 nv_id, 'Q' val from dual ) n
on (o.nv_id = n.nv_id)
when matched then update set val = n.val
when not matched then 
  insert (o.nv_id, o.val)
  values (n.nv_id, n.val);
```

Even if this does not solve your problem you should not generate `id`s as `max() + 1`, this causes problems with concurent sessions, commits, multi inserts etc.

Comment: OK, understood - particularly about the `max() + 1` issues with concurrency. 

Unfortunately, the database schema isn't mine to mess around with so I need to go back and discuss this with the provider. 

I'll mark the question as answered, though so thank you.